# Isotrophy length inside material

Tags: spacetime, symmetry

> The word “isotropy” means the same in all orientations. Hence isotropic material has the same properties in all directions. If you choose any point inside the material, isotropic materials have the same properties in all directions.

At point A, property of material should be the same in all directions around A, but it doesn't have to be the same as the property of point B in the same material. How do we define how far around A the property should be the same in all directions? do we mean infinitesimal?